# MapKit. How to dynamically set the zoom level?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I've got a problem setting zoom in the map. I mean, I can set it manually, but I need to set it dynamically, depending on the distance between two points

The code I use for setting zoom is:

```
  func centerToLocation(_ location: CLLocation, regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 5000000) {
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
      center: location.coordinate,
      latitudinalMeters: regionRadius,
      longitudinalMeters: regionRadius)
    
    setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
  }
}
```

**regionRadius** is the value for zoom.

Thanks!

Comment: Zoom and regionRadius are different things. Could you clarify what you have? Two coordinates and you want to show both on the map?

Comment: @GerdCastan. Almost that. I have coordinates of buildings of different clinics, the number of coordinates depends on the clinic itself. And I want to set zoom according to the distance between the buildings, so that it was not like there are two points located in 10 km and zoom is 1000 km. This may be confusing. Please let me know if I need to clarify something again